# Anomaly in Photoelectric effect

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, material-science, photoelectric-effect, infrared-radiation

Good day.

While doing a physics experiment for a university assignment, I was tasked with measuring the maximum wavelength at which a potassium cathode shined by a monochromatic light emits electrons.

[image]

[image]

The inside of "Fototubo" is schemed in the second image, so the anode is not your typical anode in these types of experiments, its a metal ring of an unknown material that lets photons come in to normally collide with the cathode. (The filter is a Thorlabs Kurios WB 1)

[image]

The results in a typical frequency range are coherent, despite the work function not coinciding totally with the known work function of Potassium, the estimation of the planck constant is correct. But searching through the literature, we found that we should not see a current in the red frequencies given a Potassium cathode. The problem becomes worse when we use an infrared LED:

[image]

We have tried with 3 different criteria for determining V0, even choosing by hand the best points to get a linear function, but it always shows this logarithmic pattern and we cannot figure out what went wrong.

[image]

For adjusting we used this function (Which we suspect, has no physical meaning, but the pattern is clear). If we interpret C as the minimum frequency for photoelectric effect, we get 748nm as the maximum wavelength, which is kind of absurd because the metal with the highest maximum wavelength is cesium at aproximately 665nm.

Any help getting this sorted out will be appreciated, and even more so if citations are provided. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Please consider writing the equations using dollar signs instead of using pictures. For example `$E=mc^2$` produces $E=mc^2$. For more examples see [mathjax basic tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)